# I need to extract all words prior to 4th Space in a line

Tags: regex

Good Day

I need to extract all words prior to 5th Space in a line.

**Sample Data**

Article Number Crt.DI No. **Date**
6ZZ 999 123 S 000000093 19.01.2021
**Article** description Replace DI No. Date

I have written a expression to extract what is in between **Date** and **Article** and the result is this

```
(?<=Date)(.|\n)*(?=Article)
```

6RU 999 123 S 000000093 19.01.2021

however I need to retrieve all those characters before the 4 space

**6ZZ 999 123 S**

This is a material number and this can be 13 or 14 characters before the 4th space.

Appreciate your support.

**Sample Data**

Article Number Crt.DI No. **Date**

6RU 999 123 S 000000093 19.01.2021

**Article** description Replace DI No. Date

(**Please Note :** There is new lines in between, these are three consecutive lines and each line is followed by an enter key)

Regards,
Manjesh

Comment: Please never use `(.|\n)*`, see [why in this YT video of mine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEobSs-ZCSE).

Comment: Use `(?s)(?<=Date\n)\S+(?:\s+\S+){3}(?=.*?Article)`, see https://regex101.com/r/CWwIyP/1. Anyway, the answer below also provides working solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capture group, and use `\s` to match a whitespace character or a newline.

The capture group approach can be more flexible in case you want to match more than one whitespace chars or newlines after Date and a quantifier in a lookbehind assertion is not supported.

```
\bDate\s+(\S+(?:\s+\S+){3})[\s\S]*?\bArticle\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rY7Atq/1).

Or using lookarounds to get a match only.

```
(?<=\bDate\s)\S+(?:\s+\S+){3}(?=[\s\S]*?\bArticle\b)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=\bDate\s)` Positive lookbehind to assert `Date` to the left followed by a whitespace char that can also match a newline
- `\S+` Match 1 or more non whitespace chars
- `(?:\s+\S+){3}`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead to assert that what at the right is

  - `[\s\S]*?` Match any character including newlines
  - `\bArticle\b` Match the word Article
- `)`  Close the lookahead

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SPehqM/1).

Comment: Hi, Good Day. I tried it is not working. After the **Date** there is an enter key, which it has not reflected when I had pasted

Comment: @manjeshkumar Then it could be like this `\bDate\s+(\S+(?:\s+\S+){3})[\s\S]*?\bArticle\b` https://regex101.com/r/rY7Atq/1 Or like this `(?<=\bDate\s)\S+(?:\s+\S+){3}(?=[\s\S]*?\bArticle\b)` https://regex101.com/r/pa6b1D/1

Comment: Hi, When I run both the expressions in REGEX it is working however when I paste this in the "Matches Activity" in uipath, the first expression is working and the out put is **2Q0 937 089 C 000000005 19.01.2021**, however the second expression just gives a blank output. I would require the second expression to work.

Comment: @manjeshkumar I think in that case you could repeat the whitespaces 0+ times instead `(?<=\bDate\b\s*)\S+(?:\s+\S+){3}(?=[\s\S]*?\bArticle\b)` See this [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbDate%5cb%5cs*%29%5cS%2b%28%3f%3a%5cs%2b%5cS%2b%29%7b3%7d%28%3f%3d%5b%5cs%5cS%5d*%3f%5cbArticle%5cb%29&i=Article+Number+Crt.DI+No.+Date+6ZZ+999+123+S+000000093+19.01.2021+Article+description+Replace+DI+No.+Date%0d%0a%0d%0aArticle+Number+Crt.DI+No.+Date%0d%0a6ZZ+999+123+S+000000093+19.01.2021%0d%0aArticle+description+Replace+DI+No.+Date)